# UIButton inside UIView inside UIScrollView not firing tap action

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I've been looking for this for hours and have no luck yet. I want to use two custom views inside a scrollview. The first view have a button as a subview that leads the user to the next page(scrolls down). But the button action it's never fired. If I use the button as a scrollview subview everything works fine, but that's not what I want.

The code for the scrollview view controller:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        let redView = View1()
        redView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(redView.view!)

        let blueView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.scrollView.frame.height, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height))
        blueView.backgroundColor = .blue
        self.scrollView.addSubview(blueView)

        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height * 2)
    }

    func go(to page: Int) {
        let y = CGFloat(page) * self.scrollView.frame.size.height
        self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: y), animated: true)
    }
}
```

[ScrollView Storyboard Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IpkA.png)

The code of the View1 Class:

```
    class View1: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func didTouchUpInsideMoreInfoButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print("test")
    }
}
```

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where about is the button? I'm not seeing any buttons in your code

Comment: It is on a xib file. I'm only connecting the IBAction to the View1 class.

Comment: We could come up with a fix to your problem but based on your code I would suggest relearning `Auto Layout` and `UIScrollView` and how they work together before you proceed. Apple's documentation is really good in this area: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2154/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013309-CH1-TNTAG3

Comment: This is just a sample code to show my point. What exactly is the problem with my code?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your button is actually connected to the action?

Comment: Yes, I also try to do the action using code, also no lucky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn out that I was using a view controller's view and for some reason, the selectors don't work this way. So, what I did was to create a UIView only and then everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the buttons userInteraction is enabled.
2. Sometimes if your button is inside another view, a UIView for example, it doesn't allow you to tap it. To fix this, you might want to add the button ON TOP of that view but not inside it. Make sure it's above but not inside any view in on your storyboard.

Comment: The button userInteraction is enable. I check this in run time. My button is a View1 subview. View1 is a UIViewController. I need this button to be inside the View1 otherwise I'll need to build my whole layout without it and added it later, what seems very bad as an architecture decision.